# Graphite input in Logstash

Tags: logstash, graphite

Has anyone used Graphite as an input in Logstash?

Graphite has both an input and output available in logstash.

How did you proceed?

Comment: Have you tried writing an input{} stanza?

Comment: There's already an input available. No need to write anything. I was wondering about ou implementing it.

Comment: What's in your input stanza?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have successfully captured input data in Graphite format. I’m a Logstash newbie, but I think you will need to extract the data using a filter.

See below example, but I think this will only work for single metrics, not the pickle format.

```
input {
    graphite {
        port => 2003
        type => "graphite-format-metrics"
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "graphite-format-metrics" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{DATA:metric_name} %{NUMBER:metric_value:float} %{POSINT:timestamp}" ]
        }
    }
}
```